# Deaths of both Romeo and Juliet or death of both Romeo and Juliet

Tags: grammar, agreement

I was writing an essay about Romeo and Juliet when I faced this problem.

Is it "deaths of both Romeo and Juliet" or "death of both Romeo and Juliet"? I think the prepositional complement has to agree with "death" (what is this "death" in terms of grammar anyway? Subject?), but I am not entirely sure. Please help!

Comment: "death" in terms of grammar is most likely the subject noun, but it depends on the context. Can you give an example sentence?

Comment: @AMACB...this romantic epic ended with a tragedy with the deaths of both Romeo and Juliet.

Comment: ("Deaths" is the object of a preposition, and "of both Romeo and Juliet" is a prepositional phrase describing "deaths.") "Romeo and Juliet" is joined by a conjunction, so it functions as a plural noun. Therefore, "deaths" should be plural.

Comment: @AMACB https://webapps.towson.edu/ows/prepositions.htm According to this, "Romeo and Juliet" should be the object of the preposition "of".

Comment: @AMACB But does it make difference?

Comment: No, I was just answering my own question.

Comment: @AMACB Hm? I didn't mean any offense.

Comment: If you get rid of the word _both_ in your example sentence, do you still feel unsure about which noun (_death_ or _deaths_) to use? If not, my advice is to get rid of _both_ and use the form of the noun that sounds right to you.

Comment: @SvenYargs Both death and deaths sound right to me...which rises even more ambiguity for me.

Comment: I look at it this way: Juliet simulated death, and then Romeo actually died, and then Juliet actually died. That's one simulated death and two real deaths. So if you're talking about the two real deaths, I don't see why you would be tempted to refer to them as "a death" or "the death." The tragedy may be singular, but the deaths are plural.

Comment: @SvenYargs Yes, yes. Your explanation is very logical, and I agree with you. But DAVE had some different opinion, asserting that "...you'd have a useless repetition with a plural & "both" for the only 2 pax who died". So is "deaths" redundant?

Comment: No, I think _both_ is redundant, not _deaths_ (or _death_): "the deaths of both Romeo and Juliet" doesn't say anything more than "the deaths of Romeo and Juliet" says. And likewise, "the death of both Romeo and Juliet" doesn't say anything more than "the death of Romeo and Juliet" says. That's why I suggested dropping _both_ out of the equation. You gain nothing by including it, and its presence may make it more difficult for some people (including you) to figure out whether "death" or "deaths" is the more appropriate noun.

Answer (score 1):

My interpretation is that if one were referring to a singular event that is the death of both of them, then the phrase would be **"the death of both Romeo and Juliet"**. However, if one were referring to both of their deaths in a non-collective manner (as I would, considering they died at different times, and of different reasons), then the phrase would be **"deaths of both Romeo and Juliet"**.

Poster's note: I'm having difficulty finding verification of this, so take this with a grain of salt. If someone find a source that verifies/denies this interpretation, then I'll remove/edit this answer accordingly.

Comment: For verbs, if two singular subjects express one idea then the verb may be singular (example: "the horse and carriage is waiting").  Applying the same rule to noun (*death*) and complements(*Romeo and Juliet*) confirms your interpretation.

Comment: @Graffito So...both _death_ and _deaths_ are plausible?

Comment: Yeah, but as indicated above, I believe they mean slightly different things. I'd advise going with "deaths" for most cases when talking about Romeo and Juliet. I'll see if I can get a friend who's a Linguistics major to look at it, though.

Comment: @Mercutio - As the death(s) of Romeo and Juliette can be considered as a unique event in the drama (it's a matter of opinion), I would use the singular.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what would say our grammar, but it could be *deaths* or *death* of R. & J. (which would allow you to skip here "both") & never *deaths of both* R. & J.,  because you'd have a useless repetition with a plural & "both" for the only 2 pax who died.

Comment: Why never? I thought that "deaths" is possible because, for some unknown reasons I could not confirm with a source, they have to agree. Or am I completely wrong here?

Comment: Never, because with a plural for deathS & the only 2 subjects who died you never have to be so heavy in your sentence with en extra "both" which add no precision at all.